# Pyplot scatterplot interfering with line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

So I have a list of numbers as well as the mean and standard deviation of this list. I am attempting to plot the numbers as x values and then plot the lists standard distribution on the same graph however they seem to be interfering with one another. Individually they work fine.

```
plt.scatter(class1, [0]*len(class1), marker="x", label="C1", c="black")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('P(X|C)')
plt.title('X vs P(X|C)')
plt.legend()
x = np.linspace(mean1 - 3*std1, mean1 + 3*std1, 100)
plt.plot(x, scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mean1, std1))
plt.show()
```

On the same graph:
[image: Same Graph]

Individually:
[image: Distribution]

[image]

Ideally since they cover the same x values the two graphs would just overlap, however they seem to be being pushed to the side.

Comment: What are the scatter values min and max x values?

Comment: it doesn't look like x values are the same... The scatter plot starts at x=1.something, the PDF at -2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

class1 = np.random.uniform(-2.4, -1, 100)
mean1 = class1.mean()
std1 = class1.std()

plt.scatter(class1, [0]*len(class1), marker="x", label="C1", c="black")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('P(X|C)')
plt.title('X vs P(X|C)')
plt.legend()
x = np.linspace(mean1 - 3*std1, mean1 + 3*std1, 100)
plt.plot(x, scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mean1, std1))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The likely explanation for your problem then is that somehow in your code `mean1` is not actually the the mean of the list of x values in `class1`.

Comment: Turns out my problem lied in my data pre-processing, however your solution pointed me to it. My values in my class1 list were being read as strings when they should have been read as floating point. Thank you!